# filename in Content-Disposition ignored in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, web, coldfusion, http-headers

I'm using a recent version of Chrome, and when I view a pdf in the browser I'd like to download the file.
When I attempt to download it, it is supposed to have the name "index.pdf".
However, when attempting to download the file I get a "Network Error" and the filename is "download" instead of "index.pdf"

These are the current headers I have for the chrome pdf plugin:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=index.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf;charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Fri, 07 Dec 2018 16:42:16 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: Is the `Network Error` issue only occuring in Chrome? [The `Expires` header has an invalid value of `-1`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-127), so my first question would be: what is even serving this response?

Comment: The Expires value is being added by Chrome. I think the issue is that the data for the PDF isn't stored on the server but produced on the fly. This creates problems when you try to download the file. See this issue: 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/YxyVToLN8ho

If there is a way around this other then temporarily storing the file on the server I'd like to know it.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the part about the pdf being generated on the fly.  Also include the reasons you think that might be relevant.

Comment: Is the PDF only served once per URL in your system? Chrome simply requests the PDF anew when the download dialog is used with the inline view. Chrome is certainly not aware of the PDF being stored on the server disk or not. We are generating and serving PDFs on the fly for years and that always worked just fine.